# Flask error: Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, flask

Everytime I register a new person in my website, it appears the "**Method Not Allowed**
The method is not allowed for the requested URL." Page. Can anyone help me? ///
Toda vez que eu cadastro uma nova pessoa no meu site, aparece a página "**Method Not Allowed.**
The method is not allowed for the requested URL." Alguém pode me ajudar?

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///bancodados.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Contato(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    nome = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, nome, email):
        self.nome = nome
        self.email = email

@ app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contato = Contato(request.form['nome'], request.form['email'])
        db.session.add(contato)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('https://salvacontato.rj.r.appspot.com/lista')
    return render_template('add.html')

@ app.route('/lista')
def lista():
    return render_template('lista.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

add.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registrar Contato</title>
    <style>
        #log {
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            padding: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
            border-radius: 30px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        body {
            background-image: linear-gradient(25deg, rgb(167, 167, 245), rgb(86, 86, 255));
        }
        input {
            padding: 13px;
            outline: none;
        }
        button {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log">
        <h2>Registrar Contato</h2>
        <form action="lista" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome do Contato">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email do Contato">
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

lista.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contatos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Lista de contatos</h1>
    <a href="/">Adicionar Contato</a>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for e in contatos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{e.nome}}</td>
                <td>{{e.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
        
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you have `<form action="lista" ` so you send `form` to `/lista` but you should have `action="/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
<form action="lista" method="POST">
```

so you send form to `/lista` but you should send it to `/`

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

You can even skip `action="/"` and it should send back to `/`

```
<form method="POST">
```